# How to show or hide fields with context

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

I want to show or hide fields with context.

For example.

```
<field name="cn_dn_type" attrs="{'invisible':['|',('type','=','in_refund'),('type','=','out_refund')]}" />
```

I want to add one more *"(context.get('field'),'=',False)"* in invisible. I already tried,but it don't working. It error context.!!!!

Comment: Its not supported in old version or in 16 latest version as 2023

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass logical value in context and then simply add this to field.

Try this,

```
<field name="field_name" invisible="context.get('logical_value',False)" />
```

Comment: Thank you for reply, but I want to add _context.get('logical_value',False)_ and _attrs="{'invisible':['|',('type','=','in_refund'),('type','=','out_refund')]}"_  with together.

Comment: You have to pass either each conditions in context or you should manage one logical field & value in code to add that into the attrs, because attrs doesn't allowed context.